What is 組み重ねの書棚?
This is a sentence from それから and I am not sure what kind bookshelf is 組み重ねの書棚. Is it some kind of western style bookshelf?

代助は花瓶の右手にある組み重ねの書棚の前へ行つて、上に載せた重い写真帖を取り上げて、立ちながら、金の留金を外して、一枚二枚と繰り始めたが、中頃迄来てぴたりと手を留めた。


組み重ねる means to stack objects like 重箱, so 組み重ねの本棚 likely refers to a bookshelf with grooves or something that allows it to be stacked. You can easily find such products today, but I'm not sure if such bookshelves were common at that time. I don't think there's any mention of whether it's Japanese-style or Western-style.
